# How to serve a Redis MQ requests that depends on User session in servicestack

Tags: service, servicestack, message, usersession, redismqserver

I was looking for a better approach to solve the the following scenario.

My API endpoints are currently using Usersession variables while processing the request. This becomes a problem when we have to queue the requests on Message Queue using Redis as they does not have the Usersession info available. I wonder how this problem is solved by great Minds.

Any thoughts/solutions on this are appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ServiceStack docs covers how you can [make authenticated Requests by MQ](http://docs.servicestack.net/messaging#authenticated-requests-via-mq).

Comment: That is Awesome. I googled but not able to find it. Thank you for sharing it.